# How to get a Crypto Price change (from Binance) in an interval below 1 minute?

Tags: python, api, price, binance

Ths URL below shows the changes on the price of the pair `YFI/USDT` with the minimum price change that the endpoint `api/v1/klines` can provide: `&interval=1m`.

https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=YFIUSDT&interval=1m

I seeked through all the Binance API for around 2 hours tonight and I couldn't find a way to get data inferior to 1 minute. I wish I could find something like this:

https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=YFIUSDT&interval=1s

where `&interval=1s` mean `1 second`.

Using the Binance API, is there a way to get this information?

Comment: Why don't you ask this question to Binance API support?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Binance API documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#public-api-definitions), there is no chart interval lower than `1 minute` for klines:

```
Kline/Candlestick chart intervals:

m -> minutes; h -> hours; d -> days; w -> weeks; M -> months

    1m
    3m
    5m
    15m
    30m
    1h
    2h
    4h
    6h
    8h
    12h
    1d
    3d
    1w
    1M
```

One possibility could be to fetch [old trades](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#old-trade-lookup) and then generate an `OHLC(V)` table on your own.